# Problems implementing AdMob because of Spritekit

Tags: xcode, swift, admob

After following the instructions from AdMob on how to implement their code, I faced the following problem.

I had to link the UIBannerView that was set up in the storyboard with my GameScene, this, as you might know, is not possible. So I decided to link it with my GameViewController. The problem here is that I can't decide when to show the BannerView since the value's and functions that decide this are implemented in the GameScene file. Is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks for your help,

Max Savelkoul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the methods from game scene into the view controller and call them by using NSNotificationCenter or delegation.

You could also add the banner code manually instead of using storyboard.

```
var adMobBannerAdView: GADBannerView!
```

and than set it up

```
adMobBannerAdView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)

adMobBannerAdView.center = CGPoint...
```

Alternatively I have a helper on GitHub you could check out. Also helps to keep your code clean.

https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-iAds-AdMob-CustomAds-Helper

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the first steps, however I still have some problems. First of all I get an error when changing the adUnitID (optional value etc..) . When I let it run without doing that the add is not showing up, I guess this is because I didn't add it to the view and don't know how to since it's not an SKNode. I do however load the request.

Comment: you need to use test ADMob ids to test your ads in the simulator. You can get them from the adMob website. I dont what you mean about the SKNode, maybe post some more code.